# Laravel does not create a record in `migrations` table on refresh

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I have an awkward problem, every second time I run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` the `migrations` table is empty, though it should have initial migration record added after migration: `2018_05_02_114819_add_initial_migration`

Here is my migration code (it is an import of old database schema):

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddInitialMigration extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('users')){
            DB::unprepared(File::get(database_path('sam.sql')));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');

        foreach (DB::select('SHOW TABLES') as $table) {

            $table_array = get_object_vars($table);
            if($table_array[key($table_array)] !== 'migrations'){
                DB::statement('DROP TABLE ' . $table_array[key($table_array)]);
            }

        }

        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out. It seems that in .sql file there was a line that said:

`SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;`

Which was not set back to 1 in the end of the file.

Comment: I could have searched for a long time, thinking it's a Laravel error, but a Google search saved me. Thanks!